# Get More Table Data On Page Scroll AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am populating table data with `PHP` and `JQUERY`

The problem is that the scroll function is not firing off. I do not have any errors.

I thought maybe I did not load Jquery in the page correctly so I did,

```
alert( "This means you have JQUERY" );
```

The alert function did fire off. This is a wordpress site I am working with a plugin and a template file that I wrote.

Is there any reason why the scroll effect might not work? I have never used this before. Could I possible need to load additional libraries or something of that nature?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function getresult(url) {
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "GET",
            data:  {rowcount:$("#rowcount").val()},
            beforeSend: function(){
            $('#loader-icon').show();
            },
            complete: function(){
            $('#loader-icon').hide();
            },
            success: function(data){
            $("#productResults").append(data);
            },
            error: function(){}             
       });
    }

$(window).scroll(function(){
        if($(document).height() <= $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()) {
            if($(".pagenum:last").val() <= $(".total-page").val()) {
                var pagenum = parseInt($(".pagenum:last").val()) + 1;
alert.function('Hey the scroll effect works.');
                getresult('../wuno-search/inventory-search.php?page='+pagenum);
            }
        }
    }); 
});
```

Also I am confused exactly how to add `PHP` to this function

```
getresult('../wuno-search/inventory-search.php?page='+pagenum);
```

For example if I wanted to change the url path to a variable like this,

```
getresult('<?php echo $assetPath ?> ?page='+pagenum);
```

Is that correct?

Comment: Checkout infinite scroll :- https://github.com/infinite-scroll/infinite-scroll

Comment: Thanks, I wish I would of known this 5 hours ago. haha I have been troubleshooting this all night .

Comment: Haha, I understand. Glad I could help you.